# Why does Photoshop fail to save GIF but has no problem with same GIF in smaller size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, gif

I need to save an animated GIF in two sizes: 357 by 500 px, and 860 by 1204 px.

The 356 px-wide version saves fine, but the 860 px version comes up with the following error:

[image: Adobe Save For Web Error: Could not complete this operation. An unknown error has occurred.]

> Adobe Save For Web Error: Could not complete this operation. An unknown error has occurred.

I tested making it 600 px wide and that saved fine too.

I am using an early 2015 MBP with High Sierra 10.13.3 installed.

I’ve tried deleting the various *save for web* preference files, and tried both CC 2018 and CS6. The same thing always happens. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The file you trying to export is probably too large.

Try reducing the number of frames before exporting.